# JScrollPane with RSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss, jscrollpane

I have a program where I am using a JScrollPane to display information I get from an RSS file. I want to do this all through Javascript so I add all of the information to the scroller in a js method. Here is how I create my JScrollPane and add the info in it;

```
function generateScrollingDiv(){
  //Number of events
  var numEvents = currentEvents.length;
  //Creates scroller
  $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();

  //Adds items to scroller
  for (var x = 0; x < numEvents; x++) {
      //Gets the title formatted to html
      $('.scroll-pane').append("<p class = \"rssTitle\"> " + currentEvents[x].title + "</p>");
      //Append store information
      $('.scroll-pane').append("<p class = \"rssDescription\"> " + currentEvents[x].description + "</p>");
  }

}
```

Here is my css:

```
/* Scroller used */
.scroll-pane
{
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

The problem I am having is that I cannot get the `<p>`'s to add to the scroller correctly. The information is entered into the scroller, but the scroller is not functional. I think the issue is because none of the information is entered into the tables generated by the scroller. How would you add information into a JScrollPane through javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as you did in your answer (and call jScrollPane after entering the content). However, if for some reason you need to add content to an element after already turning it into a jScrollPane you will need the [getContentPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html#getContentPane) API method as seen in the ajax example:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Needed to call the scroller after all info was entered like so:

```
function generateScrollingDiv(){
//Number of events
  var numEvents = currentEvents.length;

  //Adds items to scroller
  for (var x = 0; x < numEvents; x++) {
      //Gets the title formatted to html
      $('.scroll-pane').append("<p class = \"rssTitle\"> " + currentEvents[x].title + "</p>");
      //Append store information
      $('.scroll-pane').append("<p class = \"rssDescription\"> " + currentEvents[x].description + "</p>");
  }
  //Creates scroller (AFTER)
  $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
}
```